# Aggregating one RDD according to value of another RDD Spark (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, transformation, aggregation, rdd

I have two RDDs containing time information. RDDs are split in different partitions. 
One is of the form

```
16:00:00
16:00:18
16:00:25
16:01:01
16:01:34
16:02:12
16:02:42
...
```

and another containing span of time in form of tuple2

```
<16:00:00, 16:00:59>
<16:01:00, 16:01:59>
<16:02:00, 16:02:59>
...
```

I need to aggregate the first and the second RDD, by aggregating values of the first according to values in the second, in order to obtain something like

```
<<16:00:00, 16:00:59>, [16:00:00,16:00:18,16:00:25]>
<<16:01:00, 16:01:59>, [16:01:01,16:01:34]>
<<16:02:00, 16:02:59>, [16:02:12,16:02:42]>
...
```

Or, in alternative, something like

```
<<16:00:00, 16:00:59>, 16:00:00>
<<16:00:00, 16:00:59>, 16:00:18>
<<16:00:00, 16:00:59>, 16:00:25>
<<16:01:00, 16:01:59>, 16:01:01>
<<16:01:00, 16:01:59>, 16:01:34>
<<16:02:00, 16:02:59>, 16:02:12>
<<16:02:00, 16:02:59>, 16:02:42>
...
```

I'm trying to use the whole range of spark transformation functions, but I'm having hard time to find one that works on RDDs of such different nature. I know I might go for a `cartesian` product, and then filter, but I'd like a "better" solution. I tried `zipPartition`, that may work, but I may have inconsistency in the partitions, e.g. `16:00:00` may end up in a partition where the corresponding aggregation value (the tuple `<16:00:00, 16:00:59>`) is not present.
Which is the best way to deal with this?

PS: I'm using Java, but Scala solutions are welcome as well.
Thanks

Comment: Are the intervals always regular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I've simplified the below to use ints, but I believe the same can be done times. While the examples are in Scala, I suspect it can all be done in Java as well.*

If the ranges are regular I'd turn the "values" RDD into a `range,value` then do a simple join.

```
val values = Seq(1, 5, 10, 14, 20)
val valuesRdd = sc.parallelize(values, 2)
valuesRdd.map(x => (((x/10)*10, ((x/10)*10)+9), x)).collect
```

However if the ranges are not regular then:

If you don't mind using DataFrames then an option would be to use a **user defined function** to create a column based on if V in in the given range and join on that.

```
case class Range(low : Int, high :Int)
val ranges = Seq( Range(0,9), Range(10,19), Range(20,29));
val rangesDf = sc.parallelize(ranges, 2).toDF

case class Value(value : Int)
val values = Seq(Value(1), Value(5), Value(10), Value(14), Value(20))
val valuesDf = sc.parallelize(values, 2).toDF

val inRange = udf{(v: Int, low: Int, high : Int) => v >= low && v<= high}

rangesDf.join(valuesDf, inRange(valuesDf("value"), rangesDf("low"), rangesDf("high"))).show
```

The next option would be to **explode** out the ranges and join on the exploded version:

```
val explodedRange = rangesRdd.map(x => (x, List.range(x._1, x._2 + 1))).flatMap( { case (range, lst) => lst.map { x => (x, range)} })
val valuesRdd = sc.parallelize(values, 2).map(x => (x,true))
valuesRdd.join(explodedRange).map(x => (x._2._2, x._1)).collect
```

Comment: I'm trying to leave the use of DataFrame as a last solution. Your last option seems doable, but still I would need to explode the ranges across every second, significantly increasing the number of data (probably still better than a `cartesian` transformation). Am I wrong if I say that I might use a `leftOuterJoin` in the third row? And finally, my objects are likely to be Calendar objects (or similar): what does Spark use when comparing indexes (for example in the `join`)? Does it use the `compareTo` method?

Comment: If you have cases where `value` may not exist in any `range` then using a `leftOuterJoin` will ensure you get that value. I believe Spark uses .equals when comparing keys in a join.

Comment: I'm trying the third option, but apparently there are some problems with the join on the last step. I'm using a class MyDate to represent a Date, so that I can override the equals (I need it). Indexes in `valuesRdd` and in `explodedRange` are then instances of MyDate. Equals is actually used when comparing the indexes in a join, but apparently the join does not compare every index in `valuesRdd` with every index in `explodedRange`. What scares me the most is that, in different runs, the join returns different results (rdd of 0, 1 or 2 records, while they should be 695). Single partition used.

Comment: I'd recommend that you create a new question with a small self contained example.